# linq expressions from simple sql, seems there is limitation in linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have following sql query

```
   select * from one a
   inner join one b
       on 
       (
         a.weekday=b.weekday
         and a.starttime =b.starttime
         and a.sl>b.sl
       )
   where a.weekday=b.weekday and a.starttime=b.starttime and a.endtime=b.endtime
```

And I want it to be converted to linq statement both lambda expression and sql-like syntax. i tried but it seems like bit difficult. I have also used a tool like sqltolinq but not seem to be working.

The problem is with sql-like syntax is that my query s join has multiple elements that includes `equal` and `greater than` operator.

any help will be appreciated

Comment: `"i tried but it seems like bit difficult"` - What did you try?  How did it fail?  Did you get an error?  Unexpected results?

Comment: no when I try its giving me syntax error. I am joining between two same table. so in join statement the inner and outer source is same. so how can I use it in third parameter on join, are u getting what i am saying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ only supports equijoins, but you could do an equijoin for the weekday and starttime, and endtime parts and then a where clause for the rest.

```
// Names changed to be more idiomatic where feasible. We have no
// idea what "sl" means.
var query = from a in db.TableA
            join b in db.TableB
              on new { a.WeekDay, a.StartTime, a.EndTime }
              equals new { b.WeekDay, b.StartTime, b.EndTime }
            where a.Sl > b.Sl
            select ...;
```

Comment: can u also please add lambda expression related syntax too?

Comment: I prefer query expression form too but i like to see it how its done using lamda expression

Comment: @Alex: Well have you tried converting this to a lambda expression form yourself?

Comment: i am trying, but not succeeded yet

Comment: @Alex: Well the conversion of a known query expression to a lambda expression is pretty mechanical. See https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/28/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-41-how-query-expressions-work/ It's worth learning how to do this yourself rather than having to ask someone for every query.

Comment: I converted your query to lamda expression, but again i wanted to use `a.sl>b.sl` in join not in where extension method.

Comment: @Alex: As I said, LINQ only supports equijoins.

Comment: @Alex One is what you want, another is what you can. Read the start of the Jon's answer - "*LINQ only supports equijoins*". If the main point of your question is "*seems there is limitation in linq*", then the answer is simply **yes**.

Comment: can you clarify what is equijoin? I think of it `as join with two values and one operator and that operator has to be =`. am I right?